# Looking for a scripting to connect to a server and purge a printers print queue?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

Trying to get something like this to work against servers running 2008 and above.

```
    Dim objPrinter As Object
    objPrinter = GetObject(“winmgmts://servername/PR53”)
    objPrinter.Purge
```

Running that on server 2003 quickly purges print queue for that printer. Running that against servers running 2008 and above receive cannot create activeX.

Trying to find WMI code to accomplish the same thing. We have software running all over the US and when Zebra printers come back from repair sometimes there may be 1000 print jobs in queue. Looking for something I can include in an existing program that I wrote that configures the networking for the device before use. Would be nice while reconfiguring device the program could call routine that would purge the queue. I will know the printer ID and the server name.

preferarbly the script would be VB.

Trying to register ActiveX on all our current customers server's is not feasible.

Thanks

Comment: [Notify Users When a Print Queue is Purged](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/9f8ad84e-239d-45bf-a14f-ad8f3fc4988a)

Comment: Trying to be able to add to existing project. Don't believe I can add WSCRIPt to vb.net application

Comment: That's an example. You can use [Win32_Printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer) directly from a VB.Net Project with a WMI query. It's the same thing. It requires admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks. I found the path in WbemScripting and WmiService.

Comment: Thanks. I found the path in WbemScripting and WmiService.  Once I query the printer I want has nice objPrinter.CancelAllJobs command.

Comment: When you have the Printer object, get the method parameters and invoke the method without options. E.g., `using parms as ManagementBaseObject  = objPrinter.GetMethodParameters("CancelAllJobs")) using moResult as ManagementBaseObject = objPrinter.InvokeMethod("CancelAllJobs", parms, nothing))` . Now, if `CUint(moResult("ReturnValue"))` is `0`, then success, otherwise you have a [WMI error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants) that you have to lookup.